# Autoscale axis in Gnuplot pm3d map

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a 4 column [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsAYUX-glW_RVAySUNrYnRSNHc/view?usp=sharing) with x,y,z data (the 4th column is just a row counter) and I am trying to make an animation with pm3d map in gnuplot. Each frame is given by 10000 points in the file (the file I shared contains only 3 frames). I am able to plot the first frame with the following command:

```
splot 'data.txt' u 1:2:3 every:::0::10198
```

However, if I try to plot the second frame, for example, with the following command:

```
splot 'data.txt' u 1:2:3 every:::10100::20198
```

I am given the message:

> Warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range.

It tells me it can't auto scale any of the axis and if i try to scale it manually, it just doesn't work. First I thought I was just plotting the wrong rows, so I added the row counter, still doesn't work though.

What is funny is that **if I make this plot in the traditional splot, everything works fine**. I could just go with that, but this is a terrible visualizaiton of data in my opinion, so I'd really like to use pm3d map.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzsAYUX-glW_VzVhbGp4dGQ5MlE&usp=sharing) is the GDrive folder with 3 frames data, first frame in pm3d and the traditional splot animation

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to try plot not the first, second, third... 10000 **data-points** but the first 10000 **data-sets**.

---

```
every A:B:C:D:E:F
```

A - every Ath datapoint

B - every Bth data-set

C,D - first data-point/set

E,F - last data-point/set